# git ls-files: showing blob files only

Tags: git, git-ls-files

How do I use `git ls-files` to show files only(i.e., excluding directories)?
For instance, I want to remove `asd1` and `asd2` from the following output:

```sh
$> git ls-files                         
asd1/bar
asd1/foo
asd2/bar
base.html
index.html
list.html
```

Is there any way to do this without involving string manipulation?

Comment: Note that the above output, from `git ls-files`, contains only files. I think you were really trying to ask about `git ls-tree`, as shown in your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's the kind of thing that pipes are used for:

```
 git ls-files | while read filename; do basename $filename; done
```

I could also go this route:

```
git ls-files | sed 's/.*\///'
```

Comment: This works partially: it still prints the the files inside `asd1`/`asd2`. i.e.:
bar  
foo  
bar  
base.html  
index.html  
list.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally got it working...I leave the answer hoping will be save some else time:

```sh
git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD | grep -v -w -e "$(git ls-tree -d --name-only HEAD)"
```

Comment: This uses `git ls-tree`, rather than `git ls-files`. They do different things! ls-tree examines a tree object; ls-files is complicated, but generally starts with the index. Git's index has the form of a "flattened tree" from which all directories have been removed.